# two string instances seems same, but their hashcode are different

Tags: java, string, hashcode

```
    String a = "success";
    String b = "success";

    System.out.println(a.hashCode());
    System.out.println(b.hashCode());

    if(a.equals(b)){
        System.out.println("123");
    }
```

I can't understand why the two string have different hashcode.

```
    String a = "success";
    String b = "success";

    System.out.println(a.hashCode());
    System.out.println(b.hashCode());

    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b));
```

output:

```
-1867169789
1954952228
33263331
6413875
```

Comment: Are you sure that the hash codes are different? Post the output that you get.

Comment: -1867169789  and
1954952228

Comment: @DeanWhite - Not possible. Show us your complete code. Are you using `identityHashCode()` instead of `hashCode()`?

Comment: String a = "success";
  String b = "success";
  
  System.out.println(a.hashCode());
  System.out.println(b.hashCode());

  System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a));
  System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b));

Comment: Running your code via ideone.com shows the following result: `-1867169789
-1867169789
2430287
2430287` - what did you expect?

Comment: @TheLostMind: That is the complete code. You just didn't see the U+FEFF char at the beginning of the second string (which also explains, why the strings are not equal). Also if those strings were equal, they would also be identical, because of interning.

Comment: @fabian - I didn't edit the question.. So, I didn't know.. You are *probably right*. Since the strings are interned, identityhascode will also be same. I was just trying to check if OP was actually using literals (and not 'new String()` )

Answer (score 6):

You've inserted the zero width no-break space (U+FEFF) character at the beginning of your second string.

That string is actually equal to the following string (no hidden unicode characters): `"\ufeffsuccess"`

That means `a` and `b` are not equal and do not have the same hash code.

Comment: I think this might be the case. +1

Comment: But how to get rid of such a case?

Comment: @Salman by deleting the invisible characters of course;)  If you want to get rid of cases like this automatically, it shouldn't be too hard to write a tool going though your java source files and identify and deal with these kind of characters by removing them, notifying the user of the existance or simply by replacing them wit the escape sequence. There are already questions on identifying these kinds of chars on this site.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Compare {


    public static void main(String args[])  {

        String a = "success";
        String b = "success";

        char[] aChar = a.toCharArray();
        char[] bChar = b.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < aChar.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println((int)aChar[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for(int i = 0; i < bChar.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println((int)bChar[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

The first char of the second string is char 65279. Did you copy the strings from somewhere?

The Strings look the same, but are not. Try typing the "success" text again, then it should work.

Comment: They have different hashCode because the strings are different. The copied String starts with an extra hidden character ( as the code above shows ). It would be no different then comparing "success" and "#success" which are not equal. The hashtag is an invisible character, so you don't see it, but it is there.

Answer (score 0):

When I copied and pasted your code into my IDE, it showed that the opening double quotes of b = "success is actually a weird double quote rather than a standard double quote. Bizzarrely, I got the same result as you - code compiles and runs, but outputs different hash codes. By fixing the double quote with a normal double quote, the hashcodes are now the same.